# What exceptions does JSONEncoder.encode throw in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, encoding, error-handling

I was recently using `JSONEncoder.encode()` (and its counterpart, `JSONDecoder.decode()`), which is marked in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder/2895034-encode) as `throws`. Unfortunately, the documentation does not go into detail on when/how/what this method could throw. Does anybody have any insight in this? I'm asking because I am wondering if an error here is common enough to implement a user-facing error handling for this.

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`JSONEncoder.encode()` throws `EncodingError.invalidValue` when one of the values you are about to encode is not valid (e.g. `Double.infinity` if the `NonConformingFloatEncodingStrategy` is set to the default `.throw`, since JSON does not natively support infinity as a number).

You can see this in the [source](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/de5f7edc3040057717f7da0ba875df04d3dc3e9e/Darwin/Foundation-swiftoverlay/JSONEncoder.swift#L259), and read more about the error in the [`EncodingError` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encodingerror).